# How to find $x,y$ : $2^{x^2+y} + 2^{x + y^2} = 128$ , $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = 2\sqrt{2}$

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations, radicals, symmetric-functions

How to find $x,y$

\begin{align}
2^{x^2+y} + 2^{x + y^2} & = 128 \\[4pt]
\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} & = 2\sqrt{2}
\end{align}

I know $x=2$, $y=2$ but if they are only solutions?

Comment: You're trying to solve the system of equations in integers or the real numbers?

Comment: i'm taying in real, but i also want to see in integers

Comment: In integers note that if $x^2 + y \not= y^2 + x$ then the LHS of the first equation has an odd factor. Therefore it's easy to conlcude that $x^2 + y = y^2 + x = 6$. This implies that $x=y=2$, as the second equation excludes negative integers.

Comment: If you use logarithm with base 2 ($\log_{2}$) for both of side:
$$\log_{2}^{2^{x^2+y} + 2^{x + y^2}} = \log_{2}^{128}$$
then
$$x^2+y+y^2+x=7$$

Answer (score 1):

i found also $$x=2,y=2$$ you can eliminate $y$ and you will get the following equation
$$2^{x^2+(2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{x})^2}+2^{x+(2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{x})^4}=128$$
for $x$ and we will find again $x=2$